# Django beginner - how to separate the view and template?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am new to django. How can turn this default from django into separate view and template?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE"><title>Welcome to Django</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; }
    h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
    h2 span { font-size:80%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
    h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
    table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
    tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    thead th {
      padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left;
      font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    tbody th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #summary { background: #e0ebff; }
    #summary h2 { font-weight: normal; color: #666; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; }
    #instructions { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #summary table { border:none; background:transparent; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>It worked!</h1>
  <h2>Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.</h2>
</div>

<div id="instructions">
  <p>
    Next, start your first app by running <code>python manage.py startapp [app_label]</code>.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p>
    You're seeing this message because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!
  </p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

This is my django sample structure:

```
~/django_sample/
   manage.py
   django_sample/
      settings.py
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
      templates/
         index.html
```

in my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        # ex: /
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

In my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Inside index.html is just the same as the HTML and CSS code above.

When I run it on my terminal:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 15, 2017 - 14:27:34
Django version 1.11, using settings 'django_sample.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But I get this error when I access the site on my browser:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/projects/django_sample/django_sample/views.py", line 5, in index
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 25, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html
[15/Apr/2017 14:29:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 82522
```

Any ideas how I should do it correctly?

**EDIT:**

in my settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3bpqy#_n6ew(h52$6a_tfog4%$-$n=jf$p@-$ox(s!+fuwd49n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_sample.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_sample.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

First, make sure Django is looking in your app directories for templates.  In your settings.py file, look for something like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
            'loaders' : (
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                )),
            )
        },
    },
]
```

(the important one is the app_directories.Loader)

Then, also in settings.py, make sure that your app, "django_sample" is listed in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: thanks. i dont have that in my setting (see my edit above). whereabouts in settings.py should i add that in?

Comment: 'loaders' goes under the TEMPLATES list, at the same level as 'context_processors'

Comment: it seems that there are some errors in your code above.

Comment: i get this error after trying to fix that `ERRORS:
?: (templates.E001) You have 'APP_DIRS': True in your TEMPLATES but also specify 'loaders' in OPTIONS. Either remove APP_DIRS or remove the 'loaders' option.`

Comment: I expanded my example to show everything.  Oh wait, if you have APP_DIRS, then I'll bet you only need to add you "django_sample" to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: ` then I'll bet you only need to add you "django_sample" to INSTALLED_APPS` how do i add that? `''django_sample',`?

Comment: find the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings. Add "django_sample" as an item in that list.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my problem `django_sample` is a project not an app. I just want to separate the default html page that says '**It worked!**' at http://127.0.0.1:8000/